# Search by end nested relation django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-related-manager

I recently picked up an existing project in nodejs, this one is full of all kinds of problems. I decided to reconvert it for more ease with django rest framework, I try to keep the same json structure so as not to interfere with react. For the most part I don't have any problems except for some search with sequelize it searches by the last model to make the inverse relations
example :

```
 Occurence.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: TimeSlot,
        as: 'TimeSlot',
        include: [
          {
            model: Agenda,
            as: 'Agenda'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        model: Monitor,
        as: 'Monitor',
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
            attributes: { exclude: ['password'] }
          }
        ],
        where: { id: req.params.id }
      }
    ]
  })
```

with django rest framework I didn't find an "efficient" solution to start my search from the end to the beginning and/or replace the structure with to_representation() to display the relations between them.

For the total representation I was able to do this but for the search from the last one like the code given with "sequelize" (nodejs code) I don't really see how to do it.

```
class TimeslotsGetOptimizeSerializer(TimeslotsGetSerializer):
    agenda = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    timeslots_occurences = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    def get_agenda(self, obj):
        if obj:
            agenda = Agendas.objects.filter(timeslotagendas__timeslot_id=obj.id)
            if agenda:
                serializers = AgendaGetSerializer(agenda, many=True)
                return serializers.data
        return []

    def get_timeslots_occurences(self, obj):
        if obj:
            times_slot_occurence = TimeslotOccurences.objects.filter(timeslot_id=obj.id)
            if times_slot_occurence:
                serializers = TimeslotsOccurencesTimeslotOccurencesGetSerializer(times_slot_occurence.first())
                return serializers.data
        return []

class TimeslotsAgendaGetOptimizeSerializer(TimeslotsAgendaGetSerializer):
    agenda = AgendaGetSerializer(read_only=True)

class MonitorGetOptimizeSerializer(MonitorsGetSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    def get_user(self, obj):
        if obj:
            user = Users.objects.filter(monitor=obj.id)
            if user:
                serializers = UserGetSerializer(user.first())
                return serializers.data
        return []

class OccurencesListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timeslots = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    monitor = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Occurences
        fields = '__all__'
```

Thank you in advance if you have a solution :)

Comment: [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and possibly [DRF Filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)?

Comment: Thanks I'm checking now :)